# Confirm struct fields non-zero in Go

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, interface

I am trying to write a generic function that takes a `struct` and confirms that the given fields have non-zero values.

This is my function:

```
func CheckRequiredFields(kind string, i interface{}, fields ...string) error {
    for _, field := range fields {
        value := reflect.ValueOf(i).FieldByName(field)
        if value.Interface() == reflect.Zero(value.Type()).Interface() {
            return fmt.Errorf("missing required %s field %s", kind, field)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

and it works well if a `struct` is passed in as `i`, but fails if `i` is a pointer to a `struct`.

How can I reflect on the value of an interface if the value passed in is a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reflect.Indirect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect), which returns the value that v points to. If v is a nil pointer, Indirect returns a zero Value. If v is not a pointer, Indirect returns v.

If you want to check if the value was a pointer or not, check it's `Kind`, and use `Elem()` to dereference the pointer.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something like that.